# Why doesn't this Javascript code work and generate a number between 1 and 3 when I press any of the buttons?

Tags: jquery, javascript

I want the code to generate a random number between 1 and 3 whenever I press any of the buttons, which are rock, paper, scissors. I am not sure what I have done wrong as I am new to programming.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Rock Paper Scissors</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
    <script>
      display.innerHTML=Math.floor((Math.random()*3)+1);
    }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form>
      <input id="rock" type="button" onclick="Random()" value="Rock"/>
      <input id="paper" type="button" onclick="Random()" value="Paper"/>
      <input id="scissors" type="button" onclick="Random()"  value="Scissors"/>
    </form>
    <span id="display"></span>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

You forgot the function name for the onClick Event.  Adjust the code in your script tag with the following.

```
<script>
    function Random() {
        document.getElementById('display').innerHTML = Math.floor((Math.random() * 3) + 1);
    }
</script>
```

### [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/usbWx/1/)

Comment: Thanks, i have the same exact code however i was using a variable to get the inner.html, which is stupid because its an empty pan. Anyway Thanks

Comment: So I can see this is working, but how is this changing the `#display` `innerHTML` without using `getElementById` or a jQuery selector `$('#display')`?

Comment: @BlakePlumb It's just some old, hacky browser behavior kept up by modern browsers.  I'm going to add `document.getElementById` just to be safe.

Answer (score 1):

I think you missed the function definition.

```
<script>
    function Random(){
          display.innerHTML=Math.floor((Math.random()*3)+1);
      }

 </script>
```

Try replacing your   with this.
[More about Jvascript functions](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_functions.asp)

Your working code here

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Rock Paper Scissors</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
<script>
    function Random(){
        display.innerHTML=Math.floor((Math.random()*3)+1);
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form>
    <input id="rock" type="button" onclick="Random()" value="Rock"/>
    <input id="paper" type="button" onclick="Random()" value="Paper"/>
    <input id="scissors" type="button" onclick="Random()"  value="Scissors"/>
</form>
<span id="display"></span>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to call a function that is not defined any where.